# Combine data from 2 different lists of dataframes and 1 dataframe to create a list of charts using GGplot R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

I want to combine information from multiple sources to draw different aspects of a series of charts.  The different charts represent different Elements, but for each chart I am trying to combine a boxplot, a scatter plot, line of best fit with equation, a line for the mean value for each analyte and 3 std dev for each. I have all the data I need to draw want I want and stuck assembling it all to get the desired output.

what I am looking for is something that looks like the image below but for each analyte within my dataframe

[image]

A snippet of my lists

```
df <- structure(list(SampleNo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("151868", "151959", "152253", "151637", 
"152382", "152490", "152528", "152581", "152985", "152738", "153005", 
"153337"), class = "factor"), Rep_No = c("1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"), Fe = c(57.24, 57.12, 57.2, 
57.13, 57.21, 57.14, 57.16, 57.31, 57.11, 57.18, 57.21, 57.12, 
57.14, 57.17, 57.1, 57.18, 57, 57.06, 57.13, 57.09, 57.17, 57.23, 
57.09, 57.1), SiO2 = c(6.85, 6.83, 6.7, 6.69, 6.83, 6.8, 6.76, 
6.79, 6.82, 6.82, 6.8, 6.86, 6.9, 6.82, 6.81, 6.83, 6.79, 6.76, 
6.8, 6.88, 6.83, 6.79, 6.8, 6.83), Al2O3 = c(2.9, 2.88, 2.88, 
2.88, 2.92, 2.9, 2.89, 2.87, 2.9, 2.89, 2.9, 2.89, 2.89, 2.88, 
2.89, 2.91, 2.91, 2.91, 2.9, 2.9, 2.91, 2.91, 2.88, 2.86)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

my first list data

```
l1 <- list(Fe = structure(list(hm = 57.2, hsd = 0.295156858558032, 
    hmin = 56.3145294243259, hmax = 58.0854705756741), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), SiO2 = structure(list(hm = 6.7497718955, hsd = 0.111404744433739, 
    hmin = 6.41555766219878, hmax = 7.08398612880122), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), Al2O3 = structure(list(hm = 2.8925, hsd = 0.0725002768867193, 
    hmin = 2.67499916933984, hmax = 3.11000083066016), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)))


l2 <- list(Fe = "italic(y) == \"1.5\" + \"0.000000000000001\" %.% italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.00000000000000000000000000000114\"", 
    SiO2 = "italic(y) == \"1.5\" + \"0.000000000000001\" %.% italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.00000000000000000000000000000114\"", 
    Al2O3 = "italic(y) == \"1.5\" + \"0.000000000000001\" %.% italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.00000000000000000000000000000114\"")
```

My code that seems to get me most of the way

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales) 
library(ggpmisc)

H.PlotOrder <- unique(df$SampleNo) 
H.Charts <- df %>% mutate(SampleNo = factor(SampleNo, levels = H.PlotOrder)) 
imap(l1, ~{
  ggplot(H.Charts, outlier.shape = NA, 
         mapping = aes(x = SampleNo, y = .data[[.y]], color = SampleNo)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(.y),max(.y))))+
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = SampleNo, y = .data[[.y]])) +
    geom_smooth(formula = y~x, mapping = aes(label = l2),parse =T, method = "lm",hjust =-0.35)+
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]))) + 
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]])
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]) 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, "Manufacturing Assessment")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position = "None") +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> H.PlotList
```

It runs but when I try to view an individual chart I get the following error message
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24): label

An example of it working a single dataframe when not in a series of list

```
df2 <- structure(list(Sample = c(2113, 2113, 2114, 2114, 2115, 2115, 
2116, 2116, 2117, 2117, 2118, 2118, 2119, 2119, 2120, 2120, 2121, 
2121, 2122, 2122, 2123, 2123, 2124, 2124), Rep_No = c("A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), Fe = c(57.24, 57.12, 
57.2, 57.13, 57.21, 57.14, 57.16, 57.31, 57.11, 57.18, 57.21, 
57.12, 57.14, 57.17, 57.1, 57.18, 57, 57.06, 57.13, 57.09, 57.17, 
57.23, 57.09, 57.1), SiO2 = c("6.85", "6.83", "6.7", "6.69", 
"6.83", "6.8", "6.76", "6.79", "6.82", "6.82", "6.8", "6.86", 
"6.9", "6.82", "6.81", "6.83", "6.79", "6.76", "6.8", "6.88", 
"6.83", "6.79", "6.8", "6.83"), Al2O3 = c("2.9", "2.88", "2.88", 
"2.88", "2.92", "2.9", "2.89", "2.87", "2.9", "2.89", "2.9", 
"2.89", "2.89", "2.88", "2.89", "2.91", "2.91", "2.91", "2.9", 
"2.9", "2.91", "2.91", "2.88", "2.86")), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), class = "data.frame")

a <- "italic(y) == \"73\" + \"-0.0074\" %.% italic(x) * \",\" ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ \"=\" ~ \"0.158\""

p <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Sample, y = Fe))+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Sample, y = Fe, color = as.factor(Sample))) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~x , mapping = aes( label = a), parse = TRUE, method = "lm", hjust = -0.35 ) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = min(Sample) - 1, y = Fe)) +  
  theme(legend.position = "None") +
  labs(title = "Lab Test Order Fe", x = "Sample No", y = "Homogeneity Test Fe %") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("All Data", as.integer(df2$Sample)),
                     breaks = c(min(df2$Sample)-1, df2$Sample))
```

```
imap(l1, ~{
  H.Charts %>%
    ggplot( outlier.shape = NA, 
            mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]]))  +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = SampleNo, y = .data[[.y]],  color = factor(SampleNo))) +
    stat_poly_eq(mapping = aes(label = l2[[.y]]), parse = TRUE, method = "lm", hjust = -0.35 ) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]])) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = min(as.numeric(SampleNo))-1, y= .data[[.y]]))+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(.y),max(.y))))+
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]))) + 
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]])
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]) 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Manufacturing Assessment")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position = "None")+
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> H.PlotList
H.PlotList[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I can spot couple of issues already but the main thing is this line `geom_smooth(formula = y~x, mapping = aes(label = l2),parse =T, method = "lm",hjust =-0.35)`. Are you sure that is correct? It gives a warning `Ignoring unknown parameters: parse, hjust 3: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label`

Comment: The issue is that you map your list `l2` on `label`. Perhaps you want `label=l2[[.y]]`. However, as already pointed out by @RonakShah, a `label` aes does not make any sense for `geom_smooth`. If you want to add an annotation try with a `geom_text` or `annotate.

Comment: @RonakShah no I am not sure it is correct.  what I am trying to do in that section of code is grab the label from the second list l2 to match the correct element name,however, that approach has worked on a single element and substituting l2 for a single string of test

Comment: @RonakShah I have included a working example with a single dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I changed `SampleNo` to numeric that it was weird to applying `geom_smooth` where x axis is made out of `factor`. Also, move `color`'s location to inside of `geom_point`. If this result does not with your purpose, please let me know.

## Edits:

I change location of `as.numeric` to make it similar with plot above.

```
imap(l1, ~{
  H.Charts %>%
    ggplot( outlier.shape = NA, 
            mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]]))  +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = SampleNo, y = .data[[.y]],  color = factor(SampleNo))) +
    stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~x , mapping = aes( label = l2[[.y]]), parse = TRUE, method = "lm", hjust = -0.35 ) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]])) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(" All data"), y= .data[[.y]]))+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(.y),max(.y))))+
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]))) + 
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]])
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]) 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, "Manufacturing Assessment")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position = "None") +
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> H.PlotList
H.PlotList[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: it looks almost spot on. My only comments is that I want the x axis labels (sample no) to line up with the points on the chart.  And I want a box plot as the beginning of the chart but my sample code didn't include that.

Comment: @Spooked I'll take a look at it and reply again. :D

Comment: @Spooked I edit code and plot above. Please check it out. Also, you may get similar with plot in your question with change intercept of hlines.

Comment: I have tweaked your edits a bit further to separate the trend line from the box plot, but loose the label "all data"  I tried using scale_x_continuous to get the labeling correct along the bottom but without success.  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("All Data", as.integer(df$SampleNo)),    breaks = c(min(df$SampleNo)-1, df$SampleNo))

Comment: @Spooked Try to change `geom_smooth` and `geom_boxplot` to `geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[["Fe"]]), fullrange = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ("All data"), y= .data[["Fe"]]))`. But it will move boxplot to the end

Comment: cheers for your help see my final solution below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238164/discussion-between-spooked-and-park).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to community help I have a final solution

```
imap(l1, ~{
  H.Charts %>%
    ggplot( outlier.shape = NA, 
            mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]]))  +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = SampleNo, y = .data[[.y]],  color = factor(SampleNo))) +
    stat_poly_eq(mapping = aes(label = l2[[.y]]), parse = TRUE, method = "lm", hjust = -0.35 ) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, aes(x = as.numeric(SampleNo), y = .data[[.y]]), fullrange = FALSE) +   
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = ("All data"), y= .data[[.y]]))+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = as.numeric(c(min(.y),max(.y))))+
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'blue', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]))) + 
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]])
                             - (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    geom_hline(linetype = 'dashed', color = 'firebrick', size = 0.75,
               mapping = aes(yintercept = as.numeric(.x[[1,"hm"]]) 
                             + (as.numeric(.x[[1,"hsd"]])) * 3)) +
    ggtitle(paste0(.y, " Manufacturing Assessment")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position = "None")+
    xlab(label = "Sample No") +
    ylab(paste0(.y, ' values %'))
}) -> H.PlotList
H.PlotList[[1]]
```

[image]